# Is a New Jersey (United States) resident earning New York state income allowed to deduct New York State 529 contributions via form IT-203?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, new-york, 529-plan

I am a New Jersey resident that earns New York State income, and so I file form [IT-203](https://www.tax.ny.gov/pdf/current_forms/it/it203.pdf). I noticed this year something I hadn't before - the New York State [529 website](https://www.nysaves.org/home/why-ny-529-direct-plan/tax-benefits.html) mentions (under Direct Plan tax benefits, third section) that

> If you're a New York State taxpayer and an account owner, you may be able to deduct up to $5,000 ($10,000 if you're married filing jointly) of your Direct Plan contributions when you file your state income taxes

However, in the second footnote of the *same page*, I see this confusing - almost sneaky - language (repeating this just to emphasize - in the *same footnote* ; **NOTE:** double quotes are added by me to direct your attention to the possibly contradictory language):

1. `Contributions of up to $10,000 are deductible annually from "New York State taxable income" for married couples filing jointly; single taxpayers can deduct up to $5,000 annually.`
2. `State tax benefits for "non-resident New York taxpayers may vary".`

When I go to the **New York Subtractions** section - `field 29` (Other) - of form **IT-203**, there is a reference to form [IT-225](https://www.tax.ny.gov/pdf/current_forms/it/it225i.pdf). I read thru this instructional form and noticed section `S103`, describing the NYS 529 deduction. The last sentence of this section reads:

> **Part-year resident individuals only**: Also enter in the New York State allocated amount column any such contribution(s) made while a resident of New York State.

This *could be inferred* to suggest then that even though I have New York State income (mentioned to be tax-deductible on the NYS 529 website - see above), since I am not a resident of New York State, I can not deduct my NYS 529 contribution from `field 29` of **IT-203**. Why else would part-time resident individuals receive special directions regarding contributions made *while a resident of New York State*?

Can someone please clarify for me that, as a NJ resident earning NY state income, am I allowed to deduct a NYS 529 contribution from my NY state income taxes via form **IT-203**?

[Here is a related question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/54038/is-my-529-contribution-tax-deductible?rq=1) that doesn't go in to same level of detail and is slightly different.